# Delay_job gem not delivering mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, delayed-job

I'm trying to use Delayed_job to send mails asynchronously from my rails 3.1 app.

I followed the instructions on the github page but my mails aren't being sent (they were before i tried using this gem). I see they are being put on the jobs table, and they're being consumed, but the `bundle exec rake jobs:work -v` task doesn't give any output.

This is the code in my controller:

```
Notifier.delay.project_deleted(@project, current_user, u.email )
```

and the code in my mailer

```
def project_deleted(project, admin, destination)
  @project = project
  @admin = admin

  mail to: destination
end
```

EDIT: I'm also doing this on windows, and a sqlite3 db, if it matters.

EDIT2: Also, something weird: If i add .deliver, which i know i shouldn't, the task gets executed and the mails are sent; ALTHOUGH, the controller responds with this: ` undefined method deliver' for #

Comment: Can you start delayed_job worker in interactive mode?

Comment: run 'bundle exec rake jobs:clear', then create script/job_runner script as described in manual(https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) and then run it from console.

Comment: Also run 'bundle exec rake jobs:work --trace'.

Comment: How do i run the job_runner script? I tried the rake task with --trace, and no new output was given (besides the loading of the environments)

Comment: Also, something weird: If i add `.deliver`, which i know i shouldn't, the task gets executed and the mails are sent; ALTHOUGH, the controller responds with this: `
undefined method `deliver' for #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job:0xb42c394>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Notifier.delay.project_deleted(@project, current_user, u.email ) does but.

Here is what I would do to determine the issue.  First get Hoptoad configured. Then =>

```
def project_deleted(project, admin, destination)
  @project = project
  @admin = admin

  mail to: destination
rescue Exception => e
  # send error to hoptoad
     HoptoadNotifier.notify(
        :error_class   => "Unable to Send Mail",
        :error_message => "Unable to send mail. ERROR: #{e.message}"
      )
end
```